# Why the overall architecture of Android OS is a stack and why not any other data structure?

Tags: data-structures, stacks

The overall architecture of the Android OS is a Stack. What specifically justifies Stack to design the overall architecture of Android? Are all mobile OS like Windows Mobile, iPhone OS developed as software stacks? If yes then why? Why not a queue, tree, graph, heap, etc.?

For more information and clarity to my question: [The Android Software Stack](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_of_the_Android_Architecture)

Comment: I have genuinely no idea what you mean. Android uses all kinds of data structures, whatever is best in a given situation. I would think that you seriously misinterpreted something you read.

Comment: @gnasher729 I have rephrased and edited my question completely FYI. For more clarity, I have also provided a link. Thank you

Comment: @D.W. I have deleted that post from stackoverflow forum. I have now rephrased the entire question and added more info for the sake of clarity. Kindly remove the hold status. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for picking a single site to post on.  I appreciate the edit; that was helpful.  However, for future reference, we need questions to stand on their own, so that we can understand what you are talking about without having to click on an external link.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what they mean by "stack".  They don't mean a [stack data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)).  Rather, they are talking about a "[software stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack)", which is an architecture for a system that is composed of multiple layers.

Comment: I see. But how come Android OS is not on the list of "common named stacks" over there?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack

Comment: @Maxood - I don't know; I didn't write the article.  I don't think that's intended to be an exhaustive list.